# How deserialize same xml element to different classes by element attribute with Jackson? (polymorphic deserialization)

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have an xml file with the structure:

```
<actions shop_id="100500">

    <action type="refunds"> 
        <!-- properties collection for refunds -->
    </action>

    <action type="sales"> 
        <!-- another properties collection for sales -->
    </action>
    
    <action type="distributions"> 
        <!-- one more properties collection for distributions -->
    </action>

</actions>
```

How can I deserialize actions into different classes depending on the action type?

For example: map `<action type="refunds">` to `Refunds.class`, map `<action type="sales">` to `Sales.class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called polymorphic deserialization.
You need to extend your `Refunds`, `Sales` and `Distributions`
classes from a common base class (let us call it `Action`).
Put the specific properties into these subclasses
and annotate them with `@JacksonXmlProperty(...)` as needed.

```
public class Refunds extends Action {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a", isAttribute = false)
    private int a;

    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}


public class Sales extends Action {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "b", isAttribute = false)
    private int b;

    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}


public class Distributions extends Action {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "c", isAttribute = false)
    private int c;

    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

The tricky part is implementing the base class.
I recommend reading the article ["Inheritance in Jackson"](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance),
especially its section "2.2. Per-Class Annotations".
You need to give Jackson enough information about the mapping
between your subclasses and the `type` property.
(And don't be irritated by the historical annotation names
beginning with `Json...` although you are dealing with XML.)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "refunds", value = Refunds.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "sales", value = Sales.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "distributions", value = Distributions.class)
})
public abstract class Action {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String type;
    
    // no getter/setter needed for type
}
```

And finally you need a root class for representing the
whole `<actions>...</actions>` content.
Its `List<Action>` property will receive a mixture
of `Refunds`, `Sales` and `Distributions` objects.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "actions")
public class Actions {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "shop_id", isAttribute = true)
    private String shopId;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "action", isAttribute = false)
    private List<Action> actions;

    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Using the classes above and Jackson's `XmlMapper` you
are able to read and write XML content like this.

```
<actions shop_id="100500">
  <action type="refunds">
    <a>1</a>
  </action>
  <action type="sales">
    <b>2</b>
  </action>
  <action type="distributions">
    <c>3</c>
  </action>
</actions>
```